# Search Associative Array for Key/Value Match - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I check whether a key/value pair found in **$needles** is in the associative array **$haystack**, and if so append sub-array to $haystack?

**Array being searched and built upon**

```
$haystack = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [animal] => 'monkey'
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [animal] => 'lion'
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [animal] => 'monkey'
            )
        )
    )
```

**Array being looped through**

```
$needles =  = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [animal] => 'monkey'
            )
        )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [animal] => 'ape'
            )
        )
        [3]...[99]
    )
```

**Working Option --- Would like a more efficient method**

```
foreach( $needles as $needle ){
    if(count($haystack)){
        $have_record = false;
        foreach( $haystack as $h ){
            if( $needle['animal'] === $h['animal'] ) {
                $have_record = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!$have_record)
            array_push( $haystack, array( 'animal' => $needle['animal']) );
    } else {
      array_push( $haystack, array( 'animal' => $needle['animal']) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that you original array? Else you can modified your array for better use. As it seems you had a same key over here

Comment: I'm ultimately looping through one array ($needles) and building a new array ($haystack)... so I'm having to check the loop against the new array to ensure the [animal] keys are unique. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: means the situation is like you are building new array from an existing array but WITHOUT ANY KIND OF REPETITION.. is it?

Comment: @Suyog The foreach would need to check the [animal] key. If exists and value is equal, keep going; if not, push key in subarray... and so on.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Suyog I've provided further context in the post. Thanks for your work so far.

Comment: what if you replace `echo "found";` with `array_push( $hayst...` in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function find_key_value($array, $key, $val)
    {
        foreach ($array as $item)
        {
           if (is_array($item))
           {
               find_key_value($item, $key, $val);
           }

            if (isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] == $val) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

print_r(find_key_value($array, 'animal', 'monkey'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php
$haystack=array(0=>array('animal'=>'monkey'),array('animal'=>'loin'),array('animal'=>'monkey'));
$needles =array(0=>array('animal'=>'monkey'));
echo $r=isMatch($haystack,$needles);

function isMatch($haystack,$needles){
$haystack_val=array_column($haystack, 'animal');
$needles_val=array_column($needles, 'animal');
$result=array_diff($haystack_val,$needles_val);
if(count($result) > 0){
    return "false";
}else
 return "true";

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($needles as $i => $needle){
    if(isset($needle['animal']) && isset($haystack[$i]['animal']) && ($needle['animal']==$haystack[$i]['animal']) ) {
        //put your required code 
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the key of the $needles array won't necessarily match the key of the $haystack array.